# Connection strings asp.net 4.0 and SQL Server 2008

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have two different databases `database1` and `database2` in my SQL Server 2008 and I want to use both of the databases in my cms which I am building in asp.net 4.0.

The scenario is some thing like that:

1. two databases `database1` and `database2`
2. both have `user` table with columns `username` and `password`, now I have to use both databases for login purpose as well.
3. In CMS I have to build 3 different environments "DEV" "INT" and "PROD". They will act accordingly based on which environment we are working.
4. I am also using stored procedure to access the data from database.

If the information you feel is incomplete then you can ask, but I want to know what code should I include in connection class and `web.config` file.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is unclear and you need to add more details before anyone can answer it. Do you want to connect to the two databases at the same time? Or do you want to connect to just one of those databases depending on the active "environment"? What's in your Connection class? How does it work with the Web.config?

Comment: yes i want to connect to the two databases (having DEV, INT and PROD enviornment again) at the same time and Connection class is the code behind page and it will determine database by enviornment.

Comment: It would really help if you show some code for the Connection class.

Comment: if you are using sql helper call then just need to change the connection string when ever you pulling data from database

Answer (score 0):

you can take two variables in your connection class . one for development and one for production and take one variable in web.config for CMS . web.config variables will be set from your CMS . then check that web.config variable at the time of connecting to database if CMSvariable = "developement" then use developement connection string variable from your class other wise use production connection string variable from your class .